# How to make search provider persistent in Chrome guest mode?

Tags: google-chrome

When using chrome in guest mode, the search provider is always set to Google. I can change that do DDG or whatever, but the change does not persist: When closing the guest window and starting a new one, it's set to Google again. This is consistent with the idea of guest mode being a special "profile" that can not be altered, but:

Is there any way I can make that change persist?